# Apa reference format

Tags: bibliographies, errors, natbib

Good day,

I just finished writing my MSc dessertation and I am asked to change the references to apa style but I've been having problem with that. It gives errors that the. Sty files not found.

Please can you please give me a summary of how to use this like the installation of the packages, what to add in the preamble, etc

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you have a specific problem with specific code we naturally need a [reduced example of that code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) and, i.e., the exact error message you get. BTW: I would recommend to use [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) + [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) + [`biber`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biber) instead of `natbib` if you need a real apa style and not only some authoryear style.

Comment: I wish people would read the basics, instead of just asduming stuff. Yesterday a report about missing bibtex.sty.